# Azure Data Factory Export Structured and Unstructured Data Into The Same CSV File

Tags: azure-data-factory, export-to-csv

I export a table data into a csv file, that's ok but in addition, I'm trying to add a footer summary end of the file, but footer format is json that doesn't match with csv structure. That's why I can't merge these 2 files. Is there any way to merge these files or other way to export footer information?

Final output of csv should be like this

```
EmpNum|EmpName|Country
1|Steven|USA
2|Jack|USA

{"AuditValidation":{"RecordCount":"2","ColumnOrder":"\"EmpNum\",\"EmpName\",\"Country\""}}
```

I can export structured data from table to csv, and can generate footer information, but can't export it into the same file, and when I export to a different file, then I can't merge these 2 files.

Answer (score 0):

- I have used lookup activities and copy data activity to achieve the requirement for the given example.
- Use lookup activity on the csv file with the following dataset configuration:

[image]

- This would give the look up debug output as shown in the below image:

[image]

- Now, use another lookup on the JSON file (footer). The look up debug output would be as shown below:

[image]

- Using a set variable activity, use the above outputs to build the required structure:

```
@{activity('csv').output.value[0]['Prop_0']}

  
@{activity('json').output.value[0]}
```

[image]

- You have to write this value into a file to get the desired result. Take the following file as copy data activity source (one row and one column)

[image]

- Add an additional column with value as dynamic content. Use the above variable value in the pipeline expression builder.

[image]

- Create a sink dataset with the following configurations:

[image]

- In the mapping, only keep the newly created column and delete the rest.

[image]

- When you run the pipeline, you will get the desired results. The following is how the output file would look like:

[image]